# Loop through class method OOP+PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have a class called POSTS and here is the code:

```
<?php
// This is a class file:
        class POSTS {
            private $connection;
            public $title;
            public $details;

            // This connection coming from another PDO file.
            function __construct($dbConn) {
                $this->connection = $dbConn;
            }

            public function getRealtedPosts($section_name) {
                $stm = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE section_name !=:Section_name");
                $stm->bindParam(":Section_name", $section_name);
                $stm->execute();

                $results = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->title = $results->title;
                $this->details = $results->details;
            }
        }

        // Here the Index File:
        // I already Initiated the class and connection by
        // required the PDO file.

        $section_name = 'PHP';

        while ($POSTS->getRealtedPosts($section_name)) {
            $post_title = $POSTS->title;
            $post_details = $POSTS->details;
        ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h1><?php echo $post_title;?></h1>
                <p><?php echo $post_details;?></p>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

Unfortunately the output is nothing :( however if I removed the while loop only one row is appeared.
Also I tried to make the loop inside my class file but it didn't work.

Help please.

Comment: You are searching for not equals it is right? You don't even need to valorise your object in that way, just use PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "POSTS"

Comment: yes that what I'm looking for

Comment: Can you add your print_r output of $post object?

Comment: In this case `print_r` print nothing also, after I add `return $results` in my class. It prints an infinity loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only fetches one row:

```
$results = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Just replace it with:

```
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Of course you then need to store all results somewhere, currently you only store title and details of one row in your class.

A complete example:

```
class POSTS {

   // the rest of your class

   public function getRealtedPosts( $section_name ) {
        $stm = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE section_name !=:Section_name");
        $stm->bindParam(":Section_name", $section_name);
        $stm->execute();

        return $stm->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
    }
}
```

Then, in your index file:

```
$results = $POSTS->getRealtedPosts( $section_name );
foreach ( $results as $post ) {
?>
    <div class="post">
        <h1><?php echo $post->title;?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $post->details;?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: That made an error: _Trying to get property of non-object_

Comment: I've expanded the example

Comment: Can I use another way with my class properties `public $title` and `public $details`

Comment: I mean can I get advantages of my current class properties?? Please say **(yes or no)** because I lost my mind last two days

Comment: It doesn't make much sense the way you have it right now. You named your class "Posts", which suggests it holds more than one. You can store them in an array in the class, but that doesn't change much of the code.